# CoreUI breadcrumb navbar ruined after importing bootstrap and bootstrap-vue css files

Tags: vue.js, sass, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

I've added bootstrap and bootstrap-vue to my project via npm. After that, I've added the top two import statements to my App.vue file. After that, it ruins the design of CoreUI's default horizontal nav bar. What am I doing wrong?

```
<template>
  <router-view></router-view>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App'
}
</script>

<style lang="scss">
    //Import bootstrap <-- Those two are new
    @import '~bootstrap';
    @import '~bootstrap-vue';
    //Import Main styles for this application
    @import 'assets/scss/style';
</style>
```

As soon as I comment them out again, the design goes back to normal, but my `b-table` doesn't look right.

Comment: Core UI uses a customized version of Bootstrap V4.x SCSS (basically you are importing two versions of bootstrap v4 CSS)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CoreUI uses a customized version of Bootstrap V4.x SCSS (basically you are importing two versions of bootstrap v4 CSS).

As long as CoreUI's SCSS defines Bootstrap v4 variables, then do this in your main SCSS file

```
// Import CoreUI SCSS
// This assumes CoreUI imports bootstrap variables, functions, etc
@import '~coreui';
// Import BootstrapVue SCSS
@import '~bootstrap-vue';

// Add/Import style overrides and custom styles here
```

This allows BootstrapVue's SCSS to use the variables overrides defined by CoreUI SCSS

Comment: Thank you very much. I got the exact same answer from their official GIT issue tracker.